# Make a JS program that solves this math equasionmi

Tags: javascript, math

So I just started learning JavaScript and I got so frustrated trying to solve this seemingly simple math problem.

(1/365)+(2/365)+(3/365)+(4/365)+...+(365/365)

I tried everything that came to my mind, from for loops to arrays to nested for loops and I can't solve it simply of my lack of knowledge.

So I would like for someone to point me on a right path, and I would be very thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of what have you tried?

Comment: Sure, I'm afraid I've overwritten my previous tries but here is my last one.

let a;
const b = 365;
let c;
let d = [];
let p;

for (let i=1; i <= b; i++){
    c = i/b
    for (p=1; p <= b; p++){
        c+c
        console.log (c);
    }    
}

I'm pretty sure I know why this is not working but still my big lack of knowledge is not letting me progress I presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a for loop and go from 1 to 365

```js
var result = 0;

for(var i=1; i <=365; i++){
 result += i/365;
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Incredible how simple it is and how close I were, I tried multiple equations and none of those worked, even using multiple variables and such. I still have ways to go but thanks for taking me on the right path and solving my problem

Comment: @TwentyOneSugars, If the answers is right, would you mind to select it ?

Comment: Sure, it just wasn't letting me do so because not enough time has passed apparently.

Answer (score 0):

More complicated, but this returns the actual **correct** answer as opposed to JavaScript's usual slightly incorrect 182.00000000006 due to floating point errors.

```
let total = 0;
let divisor = 365;
let precision = divisor.toString().length;

for (let i = 1; i < divisor; i++) {
        total += (i / divisor)
}

total = total.toPrecision(precision)

console.log(total)
```